# Error updating JScript IntelliSense with jquery-1.3.2.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Any idea..

```
Warning 15  Error updating JScript IntelliSense: ********\jquery\jquery-1.3.2.min.js: Object doesn't support this property or method @ 18:9345  '*******'   1   1   projname
```

Note: Actual File path of file which contain the javascript is replaced with ****** 
Project Name is replaced with projname

Please let me know...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Are you using V 2008? May be JS Intellisense engine is unable to work with minified version.

Use vsdoc files instead - find one for your jquery version here: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/detail?name=jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js&can=2&q= (rename it as jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js). You need VS 2008 SP1 for vdoc files to work.

See [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx) announcing vsdoc based js intellisense support. Check [this FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/18/jscript-intellisense-faq.aspx) to trouble-shoot related issues.